# post-get from particle photon to django

Tags: python, django, rest, http

i work on photon and django. i send request from photon (which can run .ino files). So i send send "POST" to my localhost ip and free host site's ip and am not able to receive "GET" the value in python/Django. 
i think i can send successfully from photon but what i should do to get the value ? 
my temp.ino is :

```
// This #include statement was automatically added by the Particle IDE.
#include <HttpClient.h>

#include "application.h"  

 HttpClient http;  

 http_header_t headers[] = {  
    { "Content-Type", "application/json" },  
    { NULL, NULL }   
 };  
 http_request_t request;  
 http_response_t response;  

 void setup() {  

   Serial.begin(9600);  
   //192.168.1.169:8080
   //my free host "heroku" site ip is: 23.23.197.77
   request.ip = IPAddress(23,23,197,77);  
   request.port = 8000;
 }  

 void printResponse(http_response_t &response) {  
   Serial.println("HTTP Response: ");  
   Serial.println(response.status);  
   Serial.println(response.body);  
 }  

 void getRequest() {  

   request.path = "/photon/time";  
   request.body = "";  

   http.get(request, response, headers);  
   printResponse(response);  
 }  


 void postRequest() {  
   // here i send value: 22345 to 23.23.197.77 . but cant get it.
   request.path = "/photon/measurements";  
   request.body = "{\"measurementType\":\"static\", \"value\": 22345}";  

   http.post(request, response, headers);  
   printResponse(response);

 }  


 void loop() {  

   getRequest();  
   postRequest();   
   delay(50);  
 }
```

my serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers

from staj.models import Info, SensorInfo

class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Info
        fields = "__all__"
        #fields = ('id', 'value', 'data', 'time')

class ApiStock(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    info = MemberSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SensorInfo
        #fields = ('id','username','firstName','lastName', 'info')
        fields = "__all__"
```

my views.py:

```
# here by def "get" i can show my database to views
#but i cant creat a "get" for receive value which come from photon like we see in temp.ino
class SensorList(APIView):

    def get(self,request):
        sensors = SensorInfo.objects.all()
        serializers = ApiStock(sensors,many=True)
        #print(type(serializers.data))
        return Response(serializers.data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create an api in your django app that accepts GET request. Use django-rest-framework

Comment: Yes, i use rest. But i dont have any idea about "get" from http (other device). Can you give an example ?

Comment: What does the rest you have do then? If u have an api that accepts GET request, then it can process request from anywhere (Whatever the device).

Can u show what you have done already (I mean the api you created for this purpose)?

Comment: Can u show the url you wrote for that view? You can just paste that line in the comment section here. What you have would work if you are not making any other mistake

Comment: from staj import views.... url(r'^sensors/', views.SensorList.as_view()),

Comment: like i sayed i can see my database's data in localhost/sensors. but my arduino send me POST. ex an integer value. i just want take (GET) that come from arduino. i tried urllib bu dose not show any think. then i tried webhooks + Django but i have error " Method Not Allowed (GET):"

Comment: You are mixing it up here. You have the right pointers already. Your api accepts GET request, so from any terminal running on that PC, you can do: `http://localhost:<port>/base-url/sensors` and you'd have a response. However if you are accessing it outside your PC, you need to make sure the other device is on the same network as your api and then use the network ip. A better option is to put your api on a remote server (You can use heroku free account, it only take 2mins to get your app running) and then access it as `http://heroku-app-name.herokuapp.com/<base-url>/sensors/` using `GET`

Comment: Actually i have app on heroku. So i think i sould do this: 1- send post to my heroku app. 2- in python do get fot that post. And i will be able to prin data as json ? Am i right

Comment: You can't send `post` to a `get` api :( You must use exactly what the api is designed for. Can u describe your use-case? May be i can suggest how to re-work your api (What data do you need the api to give you? Why do u want to do a post and not a get?).

However, you consume the heroku api (It's the best option i am seeing from what you have described so far)

Comment: Let me make a guess though. You are trying to communicate with your django app from an arduino. Create your api to respond to whatever request `GET` or `POST`, send a request from arduino and everything should work seemlessly

Comment: Well. My goal is: send temperature's value (look at my temp.ino). İ can send to my heroku app site's ip (23.23.197.77). Then in my djnago app which is work on heroku must receive "Get" that value. Then i will save that valu in db. And my rest will show me value from db. Evrey thing is done. Just i am not able to get the coming value. Rest or db not impprtant now. Just take coming value from temp.ino by python or django...

Comment: Looking at my comment above, do you understand what do now?

Comment: Yes. Just send from arduino. And will get from python. İ write arduino send code. But i cant write python script

Comment: No. You already have a working api from what u added to your question. That would work fine for you. Just make sure you are sending a valid request from your arduino. Your api receives a `GET` so send a get request from arduino and send to the correct `url`. You can use the heroku url `https://name.herokuapp.com/....` instead of the `ip` (Though the ip may work, but heroku's ip is dynamic, it changes periodically - You need to note that)
I have done the same severally (But with a raspberry pi) so their is no issh.

Comment: Thank you. That helped me. İ will try aftr a while. And share the lates solution.